# Best way to resolve exported class instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I created a module like this:

```
module.exports = function foo(){
    this.run = function ()
    {
        console.log("run");
    }
}
```

now i want to require the module in an node.js application and immediatly get an instance. I tried to get it in a simple line, but it doesn't work.
The code looks like this:

```
var foo = new require('./foo.js')();
foo.run();
```

foo will be undefined and therefore run cannot be raised.

**First** working Solution:

```
var foo = require('./foo.js');

var instance = new foo();
instance.run();

console.log('Hello world');
```

**Second** working Solution (as i understand adeneo)

```
function foo() {
    this.run = function () {
        console.log("run");
    }
}

module.exports = new foo();
```

Which solution is more common ? are there more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787074/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-new-require

Comment: ok that explains why it doesn't work. but i can't see what an apporpiate way would be to class like components in my node application. Is it like i pointed out in the second code ? is there a better way?

Comment: Generally you wouldn't use class-like modules, and if you do you'd return an instance directly or store the exported function in a variable, there's no need to call `new` directly on require

Comment: so i would create an instance of the class and attach it instead to the export ? like export = new foo() ?

Comment: That depends, why do you need an instance, and why are you using prototypes, if only to get one single new instance when you import the middleware ?

Comment: I want to build a rich domain model. is there a better apporach ?