# Can I use require() in Node.js in a prototypical way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I've been interested in prototypical programming with JavaScript, and I'm trying to figure out an efficient way of doing it with Node modules.

For example, I'd like to use a prototype to quickly create a `debug` object in each of my modules, which has a `name` property and a `log` method, constructed via:

custom_modules/debug.js

```
var settings = require('custom_modules/settings');

exports = function debug(name){

    this.name = name;
    this.log = function(message){

        if (settings.debug == 'true'){

             console.log("[Debug][" + name + "]: " + message);

        }

    }

}
```

So I'd like to know if I can use that module as a constructor, like so:

do_something.js

```
var debug = new require('custom_modules/debug')("Something Doer");

debug.log("Initialized"); // -> [Debug][Something Doer] : Initialized
```

**Will it work?** If not, what's the correct equivalent?

Comment: You're using `new` the wrong way in your example. Instead of creating new `debug` instance, you're trying to create new class instance using `require` function as a constructor. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604497/how-does-require-work-with-new-operator-in-node-js) for more info.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I've fixed it. @LeonidBeschastny

Comment: Actually, since Felix noted it in his answer, I removed the fix to keep that answer consistent with the Q. @LeonidBeschastny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` doesn't care where the function comes from. So yes, the function can be the result of `require`ing a module.

However, the module must directly export the function. In your current code you are merely assigning a new value to the **local** `exports` variable, and we all know that assigning to a local variable doesn't have any effect outside of its scope.

The module will still export an empty object. You have to override the `exports` property of the `module`:

```
module.exports = function() {...};
```

---

As pointed out, there will be problems with precedence, so you would have to do

```
var debug = new (require('custom_modules/debug'))("Something Doer");
```

Comment: Actually, [check out this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it). The local `exports` variable initially acts as an alias to `module.exports`, so unless you overwrite it, it looks like you can use it the same way as module.exports. I'm no pro at using modules in Node yet, but it's what that answer states.

Comment: Yes, `module.exports === exports` initially (I never said it isn't). But if you assign a new value to `exports`, then `module.exports !== exports`. And the value that `require` returns is the value of `module.exports`, not the local variable `exports`. Here is a simplified example: `var foo = {bar: 42}; var bar = foo.bar; bar = 21; console.log(foo.bar, bar);`. Note that `foo.bar` still has its original value.