# Using `new` and `()` with require

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, event-handling, dom-events

What is the difference between:

```
var events  = require('events'),
    emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

and

```
var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

or `EventEmitter` is pretty forgiving in using/not using `new` and `()`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604497/how-does-require-work-with-new-operator-in-node-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example doesn't call `EventEmitter` at all. `emitter` ends up being a reference to the function, not an object created by calling it.

If you meant to have `()` on that:

```
var events  = require('events'),
    emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

vs

```
var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter();
// Note ------------------------------------^^
```

Then there are two differences:

1. You have an `events` object referring to the events module.
2. You didn't use `new` when calling `EventEmitter`.

If the resulting `emitter` is identical, then yes, it means that `EventEmitter` intentionally makes `new` optional. I [don't see that in the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter), so I don't know that I'd rely on it.

---

> ...or `EventEmitter` is pretty forgiving in using/not using `new` and `()`?

The last part of that suggests you've used a third option:

```
var emitter = new require('events').EventEmitter;
// `new` -----^   but no () --------------------^
```

Having `()` optional there isn't something `EventEmitter` does; it's the JavaScript `new` operator that's doing it: If you have no arguments to pass to the constructor function, the `()` are optional in a `new` expression. `new` *always* calls the function you give it, whether there are `()` there or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the difference yourself,

```
var events = require('events'),
    emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

console.log(typeof emitter);
// object
```

but when you do something like this

```
var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

console.log(typeof emitter);
// function
```

In the first case, you are invoking the `EventEmitter` constructor function to get an object, but in the second case, you are simply making `emitter` a reference to the `EventEmitter` function itself.

As far as the `new` part is concerned, it operates on a function object. Since you have no parameters to pass to `EventEmitter`, the parenthesis is optional. But everywhere else, you need to use `(...)` to execute the function.