# Node.js difference between calls with new operator

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why are these two variables (1) and (2) not equivalent:

```
    var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

(1) `var ee = new EventEmitter();`

(2) `var ee = new require('events').EventEmitter();`

variables (1) and (2) are not the same, and I can't figure out why that is.

However, these two are equivalent (a) and (b):

```
   var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

(a) `var ee = new EventEmitter();`

(b) `var ee = new (require('events').EventEmitter)();`

**Could someone explain why this is?**

Comment: How about `var ee = new (require('events').EventEmitter)();`?

Comment: `({a: 1}) == ({a: 1}); // false`

Comment: @jfriend00 yes that call you wrote works

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26156536/1048572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated

There are two things here.

#### 1. Using the EventEmitter API

I think you're asking why `ee1 !== ee2` using the API.

They're different because the [API](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events) let's you create as many EventEmitter's as you like.

This let's you have an EventEmitter for multiple sockets, streams, db connections, or whatever you need.

You could think of `new EventEmitter()` as a factory stamping out `EventEmitter`'s

#### 2. If you're asking about this specific code, there's a bug in the 2nd version.

The bug is due to [JavaScript's Operator Order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Tl;DR, you need `()`'s around the `.` for a one-line `new`:

```
var ee4 = new (require('events').EventEmitter);
              (                 .            )   <-- do . before new
```

The issue is that `new` and `.` have the same precidence so are evaluated left-to-right.  That precedence puts it above or below the `.` operator after `require('events')`.

This code helped me understand better `node test.js`:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
console.log('require(\'events\').EventEmitter: ' + EventEmitter);

// Works
var ee1 = new EventEmitter;
console.log('ee1: new EventEmitter: ' + ee1);  

// Works
var ee1a = new EventEmitter();
console.log('ee1a: new EventEmitter(): ' + ee1a);  

// Desn't work.  Appears to be the constructor.
var ee2 = new require('events').EventEmitter;
console.log('ee2: new require(\'events\').EventEmitter: ' + ee2);  

// Doesn't work.  Undefined
var ee3 = new require('events').EventEmitter();
console.log('ee3: new require(\'events\').EventEmitter(): ' + ee3);  

// Works.  'one-liner'
var ee4 = new (require('events').EventEmitter);
console.log('ee4: new (require(\'events\').EventEmitter): ' + ee4);

// Works.  'one-liner' with parameters
var ee4a = new (require('events').EventEmitter)();
console.log('ee4: new (require(\'events\').EventEmitter)(): ' + ee4a);

// Doesn't work.  Undefined
var ee5 = require('events').EventEmitter();
console.log('ee5: require(\'events\').EventEmitter(): ' + ee5);
```

Answer (score 2):

These two versions are fundamentally different.

This one:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var ee = new EventEmitter();
```

Executes the require, returning the exports of events and then calling the new operator on the results .

This one:

```
var ee = new require('events').EventEmitter;
```

Invokes require as a constructor.

Look at a more isolated and simple example:

`new Date()` // creates a new date object

`new (Date())` // throws a TypeError: string is not a function

Comment: Parentheses do not add anything there `new (require('events')).EventEmitter` is identical to `new require('events').EventEmitter` because of operator precedence.