# `this` object in require().function()

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, require

Dealing with the [robots](https://github.com/ekalinin/robots.js) node library, I noticed that

```
var robots = new require('robots').RobotsParser();
```

differs from

```
var robots = new (require('robots')).RobotsParser();
```

The first `require` fails lamenting that a `this.someFunction()` doesn't exist, while the second succeeds.
For some reason, the `this` object in the first line above apparently refers to the global object, while in the second line it's bound to the `robots` module. Why?

The error I receive is:

```
/home/user/crawler/lib/robots/lib/parser.js:44
    this.setUrl(url, after_parse);
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setUrl'
```

`setUrl` is the actual `someFunction` mentioned in the example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP didn't follow the [usage instructions](https://github.com/ekalinin/robots.js#usage) for the repo and is then surprised that it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does require work with new operator in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604497/how-does-require-work-with-new-operator-in-node-js)

Comment: @Mathletics There is a wrong usage, but it's still demonstrating a particular case of unexpected behavior that can be answered. IMO calling it off-topic is overkill.

Comment: @E_net4 that's the beauty of the voting system: I am but one vote. In any case, an actual dupe was found.

Comment: @davide there is no relationship between `require` and `this`; `require` is merely a function like any other in JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
var robots = new require('robots').RobotsParser();
```

is parsed as

```
var robots = (new require('robots')).RobotsParser();
```

i.e. it tries to call the `RobotsParser` method of a `require()` instance. *Not* what you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

The first line makes a constructor invocation of `require`, which effectively modifies the `this` reference at the scope of the library to point to a new, supposed instance of `require`. This is incorrect, and `require` should always be called as a regular function. Adding the parenthesis (as in the second line) clears the issue, as it will instead create a new instance of `RobotsParser`.

Comment: Thank you @E_net4. I'm confused because the member access operator (`.`) has higher priority than `new`, but this doesn't seem to be a problem about operator priority. Can you point me to some docs which shade light on this?

Comment: Your problem _does seem_  to be about operator priority. Writing `new foo().a()` will call the member function `a` of a new instance of `foo`. If you are wondering how `this` works, a small search will lead you to some good sources. Have a look at [this one](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/).

Comment: Thank you, I've read the linked article on "JS Is Sexy". Still, I don't get why in `new foo().a()` the function `a` is called on the new instance of `foo` instead of the old one. If `new` has a lower priority than `.`, why is the member function `a` executed after `new`? MDN docs seem shallow on this specific detail.

Comment: It does _not_ have lower priority. The behavior is well defined and the opposite of what you are thinking. Besides, there's no old instance either, just a new one unintentionally created.